# group / sum data based on period of time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a customers table and I want to get the growth broken down by different periods say day, week, or year.  To simplify let's assume there are only 2 columns:

CustomerID, CreatedOn

Trying to grasp this concept so I can apply it to several reports I want to make.

Answer (score 2):

group by datepart(wk, CreatedOn),datepart(dd, CreatedOn),datepart(yy, CreatedOn)
When doing day or week also use year otherwise it will overlap over several years

More info about datepart here: [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are also some shortcut functions for certain common date parts since you're using SQL Server. Some examples:

Day:

```
SELECT Day(CreatedOn), Count(CustomerID)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Day(CreatedOn)
```

Week:

```
SELECT Week(CreatedOn), Count(CustomerID)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Week(CreatedOn)
```

Year:

```
SELECT Year(CreatedOn), Count(CustomerID)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Year(CreatedOn)
```

[See MSDN for full reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)

### Update

Running total sample:

```
SELECT Day(CreatedOn), 
       Count(CustomerID), 
       (Select Count(CustomerID) 
        From MyTable mts 
        Where mts.CreatedOn <= CreatedOn) as RunningTotal
FROM MyTable mt
GROUP BY Day(CreatedOn)
```

Note: **the performance of this won't be great**, but will be as good as possible if `CreatedOn` is indexed.  Normally nested selects are horrible...but given how the join works in a running total situation, you're hitting the index the same way anyway, so this in this case, it's just more readable.

If it gets to be something more complex, look at a conditional join with a sub select.  If a procedure is an option, you can up the performance even more...but if you're not dealing with a ton of data, it won't matter much either way.

Comment: how would I include a column that sums all of the periods as it goes along?

Comment: @Max - Updated to show an example.. To be clear *I think nested selects are evil*, but they're much easier to read with the same performance in this very special case.